# Wikipedia wildcard search not working?

Tags: search, wildcard, mediawiki, wikipedia, advanced-search

I'm trying to do a wildcard search on Wikipedia but the search is not behaving the way the instructions say it should. Here's the advanced search help page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Advanced_search

As an example, it says this regarding a Wildcard search:

> the query *stan will match Kazakhstan or Afghanistan or Stan Kenton.

However, when I attempt to do that search (or even click on the embedded link to that search), I only get

> the page *stan does not exist

and it just lists a bunch of "Stan" entries starting with "Stan Laurel filmography."

**Why would this feature not work? Am I missing something?**

Comment: weird, maybe the wildcard feature is broken right now

Comment: This doesn't sound like an [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question - or is SO also wikipedia support now?

Comment: The relevant manual page is https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch , not the local Wikipedia one.

Answer (score 2):

It does work, however because direct matches for "stan" are scored higher than words with it, Kazakhstan is waaaay down in results. You can try slightly narrowing the results with [`intitle:*stan`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=intitle%3A*stan) however this is still bad. However, a quick check with [`k*stan`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=k*stan) shows that it works.

Conclusion: user-written help page has a bad example.